# Как в git перенести коммиты из одного бранча в другой?

Tags: git

Есть несколько коммитов в основном бранче, как их перенести в другой?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю, что разумно использовать [`git cherry-pick`](http://technosophos.com/content/git-cherry-picking-move-small-code-patches-across-branches), хотя, в зависимости от ситуации и состояния бранчей иногда можно предложить более удобные альтернативы.